# Scrollable box with the same scrollbar height when width is changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, bootstrap-5

I have a box with two segments.

- The upper is a title, and the lower contains a `div` or `p` element that
  contains text. When the width of the box changes, the text gets
  wrapped, so the height of the scrollbar changes when the long title
  is getting wrapped.
- But I want the scrollbar and the textbox to stay the same. Maybe you
  understand my problem if u have a look at the attached pictures. I
  want the textbox to look like in screenshot 2, if the title is
  getting wrapped.

I use HTML, Bootstrap, and Javascript.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sGX4.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq9yF.png)

I hope you can help me :)

I have this code so far:

```css
.test-test {
    padding: 15px;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.test-test .test-description {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

.test-description:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="test-project-wrapper d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="">
      <img class="test-project-image" src="pictures/SB_Logo.JPG" alt="test-image">
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid flex-column">
      <div class="test-description-heading d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">loooooooooooong-title</div>

       <div class="test-test">
          <p class="test-description">
             lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
          </p>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I think it has something to do with the `max-height` property of `.test-test`